# How to query using IN for matching emails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

given a string of emails like:

```
emails = "atttt@bbb-inc.com, scott@sara.com, a@a.com, rasx@bo.com"
```

With one query, I would like to return all matching User records where:

```
User.rb (id,email)
```

Here is my query, but it does not return results if I have emails set to more than one email:

```
User.where("email IN (?)", emails)
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (email IN ('atttt@bbb-inc.com,, scott@sara.com, a@a.com, rasx@bo.com'))
 => []
```

Suggestions on how to update this User.where query to get all matching Users from the emails provided? Thank you.

Comment: Adding postgresql as a tag as that is the database I'm using with rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, turn the `emails` into an Array:

```
emails = "atttt@bbb-inc.com, scott@sara.com, a@a.com, rasx@bo.com".split(', ')
```

Then you can call:

```
User.where(:email => emails)
```

Comment: Thanks, any way to reverse this where Users NOT in the emails array? Thanks

Comment: User.where("email NOT IN (?)", emails)

Comment: It should have worked. Did you remember to convert the emails to Array first?